# Troubleshoot WebGL Support in Firefox 44 / OSX 10.11.3

Tags: macos, firefox, intel-graphics, webgl

I am using a 13" Macbook Air 2014 with a 1.7Ghz Intel Core i7 (Intel HD 5000 Graphics). WebGL support seems to be disabled in the latest version of Firefox. Running the simple code snippet

```
document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl')
```

throws `Error: WebGL: Error during native OpenGL init.`
WebGL works fine in latest Chrome and `about:support` shows these messages in the "Graphics" section:

[image: about:support]

My settings according to `about:config`:

[image: about:config]

What is the reason for WebGL not working properly? What is that dubios previous crash or how can I find out? How do I re-enable it?

Comment: Try changing the default to specifically *false*.    This also could simply be a bug in Firefox 44, try previous versions, see if those work.

Comment: I can't "set it explicitly" unfortunately. Double clicking leads to "**user set: true**" and toggling again to the very same default, which is false. This changes nothing in the observed behavior.

Comment: After you try a previous version of Firefox.  Try creating a new user profile for Firefox.

Comment: How should I go about downgrading Firefox when it automatically installs the current versions? I already tried starting it with Addons disabled which did not help. I also tried the `Reset Firefox` feature, which unfortunately also did not help.

Comment: Have you tried a new user profile?  You disable automatic updates, for the profile, before you run the previous version of Firefox or just decline the update.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the about:support page, GL has been disabled due to a previous crash on the Graphics stack. In order to prevent for more crashes, Firefox disabled WebGL, which is not very nice.

In order to re-enable it, you can simply reset the `gfx.crash-guard.status.glcontext` value in about:config.

An alternative is to clear the whole profile, but in this way you will lose all your personal settings and thus is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks! In my case I had to reset `gfx.blacklist.webgl.opengl`.

Answer (score 0):

The final solution came from the Mozilla Support Forums, specifically [this post](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1112622#answer-851023):

> Try to delete possible user.js and numbered prefs-##.js files and rename/remove the prefs.js file to reset all prefs to the default value including prefs set via user.js and prefs that are no longer supported in current Firefox releases.
>
> - http://kb.mozillazine.org/Preferences_not_saved
> - http://kb.mozillazine.org/Resetting_preferences
>
> You can use this button to go to the current Firefox profile folder:
>
> Help > Troubleshooting Information > Profile Directory;
>   Windows: Show Folder; Linux: Open Directory; Mac: Show in Finder

Comment: So the solution is to throw the baby out with the bath water? Great!

Comment: Yes, unfortunately so. I have not found another way to re-enable the the GLContext, nor could I found out what this previous crash was exactly.

Comment: As infuriating as it is the only way for me to get it back also was the destroy every profile I had. I can not understand how that helps the firefox community.